# Transform jQuery function to pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I transform this code written in JQuery to just JS?

Original code:

```
$('.abcClass').each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/([^\x00-\x80]|\w)/g, "<span class='mail'>$&</span>"));
});
```

I've tried to write it like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.abcClass').forEach(function (comment) {
    comment.innerHTML(comment.toString().replace(/([^\x00-\x80]|\w)/g, "<span class='mail'>$&</span>"));
});
```

But I've received the errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: comment.innerHTML is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
```

I'm new to jQuery so I found myself pretty much stuck at this step... any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: [You can directly assign the value to innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Replacing_the_contents_of_an_element)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `.innerHTML` *is* a function underneath, it's a setter (and getter), so you have to set and retrieve its values as if it was a plain property value:

```
comment.innerHTML = comment.innerHTML
  .replace(/([^\x00-\x80]|\w)/g, "<span class='mail'>$&</span>"));
```

Also keep in mind that `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, and NodeLists only have a `forEach` method in newer browsers (mid-2016+ or so). For better backwards compatibility, consider calling `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('.abcClass'),
  function(comment) {
    // ...
```

(pretty sure you can also do `NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach` beforehand, but that looks really weird to me)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jquery `.each()`

```
$('div').each(function(){ //... })
```

use document.querySelectorAll(), then convert the HTMLCollection into a JavaScript array. Then you can map over the array of elements.

```
 const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.my-elements')
 const $elems = [].slice.call(elems)
 $elems.map( (elem) => { console.log(elem) })
```